# Controlling a window that I did not start

Tags: c#, white-framework

I am writing a simple install script with [TestStack White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) so i can learn the framework (I didn't find a lot of info online).

I'm using league of legend install for this little experiment

after I fill the forms, and pressing the next buttons, there is a window that opens from the install program.

I want to know if there is a way to GET the window even if i wasn't the one who executing it.

this is the code i'm using to run the application, up to the moment the new window opens:

```
private void pressXButton(White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window currentWindow, string buttonName)
    {
        var xButton = currentWindow.Get<White.Core.UIItems.Button>(White.Core.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText(buttonName));
        xButton.Click();
        currentWindow.WaitWhileBusy();
    }

    public void RunScript()
    {
        White.Core.Application application = White.Core.Application.Launch(filePath);
        White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window window = application.GetWindow(windowTitle);
        window.WaitWhileBusy();

        pressXButton(window, NEXT_BUTTON_TEXT);

        var radioButtonAgree = window.Get<White.Core.UIItems.RadioButton>(White.Core.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText("I accept the terms in the License Agreement"));
        radioButtonAgree.Select();
        window.WaitWhileBusy();

        pressXButton(window, NEXT_BUTTON_TEXT);
        pressXButton(window, NEXT_BUTTON_TEXT);
        pressXButton(window, NEXT_BUTTON_TEXT);
        pressXButton(window, NEXT_BUTTON_TEXT);
        pressXButton(window, NEXT_BUTTON_TEXT);
        pressXButton(window, "Install");

//afther pressing the Install Button the program ask to install  Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package and here is where im stcuk




    }
```

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Desktop.Instance.Windows()` to get at all the windows, not just the ones in the process you are testing.

Otherwise you have to use Application.Attach("processname") to get the process of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package